# How should I modify my Queue class to allow users to create empty queues of unspecified type in F#?

Tags: data-structures, f#

I have created an immutable `Queue` in F# as follows:

```
type Queue<'a>(f : 'a list, r : 'a list) =    
    let check = function
        | [], r -> Queue(List.rev r, [])
        | f, r -> Queue(f, r)

    member this.hd =
        match f with
        | [] -> failwith "empty"
        | hd :: tl -> hd

    member this.tl =
        match f, r with
        | [], _ -> failwith "empty"
        | hd::f, r -> check(f, r)

    member this.add(x) = check(f, x::r)

    static member empty : Queue<'a> = Queue([], [])
```

I want to create an instance of an empty `Queue`, however I get a value-restriction exception:

```
> let test = Queue.empty;;

  let test = Queue.empty;;
  ----^^^^
```

> C:\Documents and Settings\juliet\Local Settings\Temp\stdin(5,5): error FS0030:
>      Value restriction. The value 'test' has been inferred to have generic type
>      val test : Queue<'_a>
>      Either define 'test' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit
>      arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

Basically, I want the same kind of functionality seen in the `Set` module which allows me to write:

```
> let test = Set.empty;;

val test : Set<'a>
```

How can I modify my `Queue` class to allow users to create empty queues?

Comment: *pojh* This should be a CW :)

Comment: Downvoters: please provide a reason why you've downvoted this question.

Comment: @Princess: Downvoting is anonymous. Why you need to know who did it?

Comment: I gave +1 after attempting to fix the title up some.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use GeneralizableValueAttribute, a la:

```
type Queue<'a>(f : 'a list, r : 'a list) =  // '
    let check = function
        | [], r -> Queue(List.rev r, [])
        | f, r -> Queue(f, r)

    member this.hd =
        match f with
        | [] -> failwith "empty"
        | hd :: tl -> hd

    member this.tl =
        match f, r with
        | [], _ -> failwith "empty"
        | hd::f, r -> check(f, r)

    member this.add(x) = check(f, x::r)
module Queue =    
    [<GeneralizableValue>]
    let empty<'T> : Queue<'T> = Queue<'T>([], []) // '

let test = Queue.empty
let x = test.add(1)       // x is Queue<int>
let y = test.add("two")   // y is Queue<string>
```

You can read a little more about it in the [language spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec2.aspx).

Comment: I could have sworn that I'd written exactly that, but it looks like you've written it better. Much appreciated :)