# Understanding F# Value Restriction Errors

Tags: f#, type-inference, value-restriction

I don't understand how the Value Restriction in F# works. I've read the explanation in the [wiki](http://www.strangelights.com/fsharp/wiki/default.aspx/FSharpWiki/ValueRestriction.html) as well as the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183(VS.100).aspx). What I don't understand is:

1. Why, for example, this gives me a Value Restriction error (Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416508/f-compiler-error-fs0030-problems-with-the-value-restriction) question):

   ```
   let toleq (e:float<_>) a b = (abs ( a - b ) ) < e
   ```

   But ths doesn't:

   ```
   let toleq e (a:float<_>) b = (abs ( a - b ) ) < e
   ```
2. This is generalized all right...

   ```
   let is_bigger a b = a < b
   ```

   but this isn't (it is specified as int):

   ```
   let add a b = a + b
   ```
3. Why functions with implicit parameters generate Value Restriction:

   this:

   ```
   let item_count = List.fold (fun acc _ -> 1 + acc) 0
   ```

   vs this:

   ```
   let item_count l = List.fold (fun acc _ -> 1 + acc) 0 l
   ```

   (Mind you, if I do use this function in a code fragment the VR error will be gone, but then the function will be specified to the type I used it for, and I want it to be generalized)

How does it work?

(I'm using the latest F#, v1.9.6.16)

Comment: Cross ref to another question on same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416508/f-compiler-error-fs0030-problems-with-the-value-restriction

Comment: Just as an update to this - case (1) was likely a bug, as it doesn't produce the error anymore.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

EDIT

Better/recent info is here: [Keeping partially applied function generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047308/keeping-partially-applied-function-generic)

(original below)

I think a pragmatic thing here is not to try to understand this too deeply, but rather to know a couple general strategies to get past the VR and move on with your work.  It's a bit of a 'cop out' answer, but I'm not sure it makes sense to spend time understanding the intracacies of the F# type system (which continues to change in minor ways from release to release) here.

The two main strategies I would advocate are these.  First, if you're defining a value with a function type (type with an arrow '->'), then ensure it is a syntactic function by doing [eta-conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_expansion#.CE.B7-conversion):

```
// function that looks like a value, problem
let tupleList = List.map (fun x -> x,x)
// make it a syntactic function by adding argument to both sides
let tupleList l = List.map (fun x -> x,x) l
```

Second, if you still encounter VR/generalizing problems, then specify the entire type signature to say what you want (and then 'back off' as F# allows):

```
// below has a problem...
let toleq (e:float<_>) a b = (abs ( a - b ) ) < e
// so be fully explicit, get it working...
let toleq<[<Measure>]'u> (e:float<'u>) (a:float<'u>) (b:float<'u>) : bool = 
    (abs ( a - b ) ) < e
// then can experiment with removing annotations one-by-one...
let toleq<[<Measure>]'u> e (a:float<'u>) b = (abs ( a - b ) ) < e
```

I think those two strategies are the best pragmatic advice.  That said, here's my attempt to answer your specific questions.

1. I don't know.
2. '>' is a fully generic function ('a -> 'a -> bool) which works for all types, and thus is_bigger generalizes.  On the other-hand, '+' is an 'inline' function which works on a handful of primitive types and a certain class of other types; it can only be generalized inside other 'inline' functions, otherwise it must be pinned down to a specific type (or will default to 'int').  (The 'inline' method of ad-hoc polymorphism is how the mathematical operators in F# overcome the lack of "type classes".)
3. This is the 'syntactic function' issue I discussed above; 'let's compile down into fields/properties which, unlike functions, cannot be generic.  So if you want it to be generic, make it a function.  (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927400/how-should-i-modify-my-queue-class-to-allow-users-to-create-empty-queues-of-unspe) for another exception to this rule.)

Comment: Dmitri has written a nice post on this more recently: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Value restriction was introduced to address some issues with polymorphism in the presence of side effects. F# inherits this from OCaml, and I believe value restriction exists in all ML variants. Here's a [few](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/meta-lang-faq/) [more](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora026.html#toc35) [links](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/FAQ_EXPERT-eng.html) for you to read, besides the links you cited. Since Haskell is pure, it's not subjected to this restriction.

As for your questions, I think question 3 is truly related to value restriction, while the first two are not.

Comment: Yes. OCaml has a relaxed value restriction where it allows non-generalized type variables at the top-level in the REPL where they are displayed as `'_a` rather than `'a`. The latter means the code is polymorphic and works for all types `'a` whereas the former means the code is monomorphic in this type and works only for one specific type `'_a` and that has not yet been determined. This is made easier by the fact that OCaml uses a uniform data representation for all polymorphic data. It would be harder in F# because reified generics need the exact monomorphic type to be known at compilation.

Answer (score 2):

No one, including the people on the F# team, knows the answer to this question in any meaningful way.

The F# type inference system is exactly like VB6 grammar in the sense that the compiler defines the truth.

Unfortunate, but true.

Comment: Well, I bet Don knows the answer.  And F# is still in Beta.  At some point we'll have to firm up the spec.  And the compiler is not a black box; the F# compiler source is freely available.

All that said, I didn't downvote you, as for the most part I don't disagree (hardly anyone 'knows', and the lack of a succinct spec is indeed unfortunate).

Comment: Every language has its nooks and crannies. F# for the most part is a very stable, very elegant & practical language (IMHO). Obviously, it is still work in progress, but compared to some other developing languages (without naming names) the future sure is bright for F#.
That said, I didn't downvote you either.

Comment: @Brian Don knows the answer only because he has access to the source.  There is no "theory" of type inference in F#.

Comment: @Dave Berk I think that F# is a beautiful language.  In fact, I run an F# user group.  However, it doesn't follow that it has a beautiful type inference mechanism.

Comment: @Brian is this still true today (2014)? that the F# type inference is tricky and only defined by the source itself? would you still answer "I don't know" to the first question?

Comment: I find these all these assertions about F#'s type inference strange. The value restriction is there to handle the case of a non-generalized type variable escaping to the top-level.