# Keeping partially applied function generic

Tags: generics, f#, value-restriction

Is it possible to partially apply a function such as `bprintf` and prevent it from being restricted based on its initial use?

I'd like to do the following:

```
let builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder()
let append = Printf.bprintf builder
append "%i" 10
append "%s" string_value
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can add explicit *format* argument

```
let builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder()
let append format = Printf.bprintf builder format
append "%i" 10
append "%s" "1"
```

Comment: Thanks. Can anyone explain why this works and partial application doesn't?

Comment: Because in .NET, functions can be generic and variables can't. `let append format =` describes a function; `let append =` describes a variable.

Answer (score 12):

The aspect of F# that's causing this is called *value restriction*. You can see that if you enter just the two `let` declarations to F# Interactive (so that the compiler doesn't infer the type from the first use):

```
> let builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder() 
  let append = Printf.bprintf builder ;;
```

> error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'append' has been inferred to have
> generic type val append : ('_a -> '_b) when '_a :> Printf.BuilderFormat<'_b>
> Either make the arguments to 'append' explicit or, if you do not intend for
> it to be generic, add a type annotation.

There is an [excellent article by Dmitry Lomov](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313200648/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx) from the F# team which explains it in detail. As the article suggests, one solution is to add explicit type parameter declaration:

```
let builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder() 
let append<'T> : Printf.BuilderFormat<'T> -> 'T = Printf.bprintf builder 
append "%i" 10 
append "%s" "Hello"
```

This will work just fine.

Answer (score 6):

You're encountering the F# value restriction.

Here's a good explanation of some workarounds: [Understanding F# Value Restriction Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131456/understanding-f-value-restriction-errors)

Here's a fairly in-depth article explaining the reasons behind it: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313200648/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx)