# Generic type annotation in F#

Tags: f#

I got the following error:

> Error  2   Value restriction. The value `'gbmLikelihood'` has been inferred to have generic type     `val gbmLikelihood : (float -> '_a -> float [] -> float) when '_a :> seq<float>`     Either make the arguments to `'gbmLikelihood'` explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

and this type is exactly what I want. What do I have to do to make it work, and why doesn't it just work without intervention?

EDIT:
The error comes from this file (its short, so I paste the whole lot):

```
module Likelihood
open System

let likelihood getDrift getVol dt data parameters =
    let m = getDrift data parameters
    let s =  getVol data parameters
    let N = float (Seq.length data)
    let sqrt_dt = Math.Sqrt dt
    let constant = -0.5*Math.Log(2.0*Math.PI*dt)*N
    let normalizedResidue observation = (observation - (m - 0.5*s*s)*dt)/(s*sqrt_dt) 
    let residueSquared observation = 
        let r = normalizedResidue observation in r*r
    let logStdDev = Math.Log s
    constant - logStdDev*N - 0.5* (data |> Seq.sumBy residueSquared) 

let gbmLikelihood = likelihood (fun data p -> Array.get p 0) (fun datac p -> Array.get p 1)
```

Comment: Can you post an example demonstrating the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error can happen when you declare a *value* that has a generic type. See for example [this past SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047308/keeping-partially-applied-function-generic). In your case, the type suggests that you are trying to define a function, but the compiler does not see it as a syntactic function. This can happen if you perform some effects and then return function using the lambda syntax:

```
let wrong = 
  printfn "test"
  (fun x -> x)
```

To avoid the problem, you need to write the function using the function syntax:

```
printfn "test"
let wrong x = x
```

**EDIT:** In your concrete example, the function `gbmLikelihood` is created as a result of a partial function application. To make it compile, you need to turn it into an explicit function:

```
let gbmLikelihood parameters = 
  likelihood (fun data p -> Array.get p 0) (fun datac p -> Array.get p 1) parameters
```

For more information why this is the case & how it works, see also this great [article on value restriction in F#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx).

Comment: Yes - partial function application is an expression (application) returning a (function) value, but it is not a _syntactic function_, so the restriction applies in this case too.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making the parameters of `gbmLikelihood` explicit you might also just add a generic type annotation to the function:

```
let gbmLikelihood<'a> = 
    likelihood (fun data p -> Array.get p 0) (fun datac p -> Array.get p 1)
```

Comment: This is the shortest solution. Thanks!