# F# partial application function wrapper does not keep return type generic for parameter function

Tags: generics, f#, partial-application

TL DR: I am trying to create a function wrapper. The wrapped function takes no parameter but returns a value.

*The reason I want to do this is to create a function similar to "lock" but for a semaphore.*

Here it is

```
let functionWrapper (param1) (f:(unit -> 'a)) =
    printfn "Calling function %s" param1
    f()
```

Signature : `(string -> (unit -> 'a) -> 'a)` 
So far, all good

Now let's enrich functionWrapper with a parameter

```
let functionWrapperFoo = functionWrapper "Foo"
```

Signature : `((unit -> obj) -> obj)` 
For a reason, *'a* becomes *obj* here..

Now I finally want to use this function to wrap another one.
But the type inference will change the signature of `functionWrapperFoo` into `((unit -> int) -> int)` which prevents from using the function with other types afterward.

```
let resultFooInt =
    functionWrapperFoo (
        fun _ ->
            (42)
        )


// Because I am using a string as a return type now, this one bellow won't compile
let resultFooString =
    functionWrapperFoo (
        fun _ ->
            "42"
        )
```

Why I can't keep this function generic after the first partial application ?

I did find a workaround but **I really do not understand the reason for this**.

I've seen some post mentioning something similar about partial application but in my case my wrapped function does not have parameters
[Keeping partially applied function generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047308/keeping-partially-applied-function-generic)

**Full original code**

```
let functionWrapper (param1) (f:(unit -> 'a)) =
    printfn "Calling function %s" param1
    f()

let functionWrapperFoo = functionWrapper "Foo"
let resultFooInt =
    functionWrapperFoo (
        fun _ ->
            (42)
        )
let resultFooString =
    functionWrapperFoo (
        fun _ ->
            "42"
        )
```

**Workaround**

```
let functionWrapper (param1) (f:(unit -> 'a)) =
    printfn "Calling function %s" param1
    f()

let functionWrapperFoo() = functionWrapper "Foo"

let resultFooInt =
    functionWrapperFoo() (
        fun _ ->
            (42)
        )
    
let resultFooString =
    functionWrapperFoo() (
        fun _ ->
            "42"
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue known as value restriction. There is a fairly detailed explanation of this in [this article on automatic generalization in F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/automatic-generalization) and there are also [good existing answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131456/understanding-f-value-restriction-errors).

The basic issue is that F# does not let you define generic syntactic values. Your `functionWrapperFoo` is defined as a value, i.e. using `let value = <expr>`. In this case, the value cannot be generic, even if the expression `<expr>` actually evalautes to a function.

Your workaround works, because it makes the syntactic declaration into a function declaration using `let func arg = <expr>`. Here, the compiler knows for sure that it is going to be a function.

As mentioned by Tom, a better workaround is to just add a parameter to your `functionWrapperFoo` definition and pass it to `functionWrapper` - that way, it will be syntactically defined as a function and automatic generalization will make it generic.

Answer (score 2):

If you define f as a value in your first `full code` section, then f becomes fully typed and thus is no longer generic. The compiler needs to infer some type.

If you make keep it a function as in your `workaround` section. It remains a (generic) function, which is why it works.

You can also specify the function argument again, which would make the calling functions less ugly:

```
let inline functionWrapper (param1) (f:(unit -> 'a)) =
    printfn "Calling function %s" param1
    f()

let functionWrapperFoo f = functionWrapper "Foo" f

let resultFooInt =
    functionWrapperFoo (
        fun _ ->
            (42)
        )
let resultFooString =
    functionWrapperFoo (
        fun _ ->
            "42"
        )
```