# How to make my function generic

Tags: generics, f#, value-restriction

```
    let csvList startDelim endDelim lst memF = 
        let listIter (listStr: string) item = 
            if listStr.Length > 0 then 
                listStr + "," + (memF item)
            else 
                memF item                
        startDelim + (List.fold listIter "" lst) + endDelim

    let listIntoJsonArray = csvList "[" "]"
    let listIntoJsonObject = csvList "{" "}"

    let intConverter (item:int) : string =
        item.ToString()

    let objectConverter (item:SomeObject) : string =
        item.value.ToString()

    let objects = [{vaue: 12.3}; {vaule: 33.2}]
    let ints = [1;2;4]

    let o = listIntoJsonObject objects objectConverter
    let i = listIntoJsonObject ints intConverter
```

I can't seem to find the magic sauce to make the csvList or its partially applied helpers listIntoJsonArray or listIntoJsonObject  generic.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your listIntoJsonArray and listIntoJsonObject are values, not functions, so you met [value restriction](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313200648/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx) monster. You can either convert them to functions by adding explicit argument or to type functions.

```
// function case

let csvList startDelim endDelim lst memF = 
    let listIter (listStr: string) item = 
        if listStr.Length > 0 then 
            listStr + "," + (memF item)
        else 
            memF item                
    startDelim + (List.fold listIter "" lst) + endDelim

let listIntoJsonObject x = csvList "{" "}" x

let ints = [1;2;4]

let i = listIntoJsonObject [1;2;4] string 
let y = listIntoJsonObject ["123"] id


// type function case

let csvList<'T> startDelim endDelim (lst : 'T list) memF = 
    let listIter (listStr: string) item = 
        if listStr.Length > 0 then 
            listStr + "," + (memF item)
        else 
            memF item                
    startDelim + (List.fold listIter "" lst) + endDelim

[<GeneralizableValue>]
let listIntoJsonObject<'T> = csvList<'T> "{" "}"

let ints = [1;2;4]

let i = listIntoJsonObject [1;2;4] string 
let y = listIntoJsonObject ["123"] id
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried the code, but in general, eta-conversion, e.g. changing

```
let myFunVal = partialApplication toSomeArgs
```

to

```
let myFun rest = partialApplication toSomeArgs rest
```

is likely to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

`csvList` looks generic enough: `string -> string -> 'a list -> ('a -> string) -> string`

But you've encountered [Value Restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131456/understanding-f-value-restriction-errors) in your attempt at partial application with `listIntoJsonArray` and `listIntoJsonObject`; you need to add explicit parameters:

```
let listIntoJsonArray lst memF = csvList "[" "]" lst memF
let listIntoJsonObject lst memF = csvList "{" "}" lst memF
```

Comment: Didn't seemt to do the trick.  Just when I feel like I am gettng a solid hold on the language it takes another turn.  Will need to research the Value Restrictions more...  Thx.

Comment: @akaphenom: my original solution had a mistake (I added the parameters to the function definition, but then didn't pass them as arguments to csvList), it should work correctly now. F# is a wild beast, but that makes the taming so much more exciting, and the rewards so much greater :)