# F#: two ways of defining functions?

Tags: f#

These two are equivalent:

```
let f(x) =
    10

let g = fun(x) ->
    10
```

I think? They seem to do the same thing, but are there any cases where the behavior of the two would vary? I find the second version useful (even if more verbose) because you can use the `<|` and `<<` operators to implement python-style decorator patterns; is there any case where I *have* to use the first version?

Furthermore, I fully understand how the second one works (the stuff on the right is just a function expression, which I dump into g) but how about the first one? Is there some compiler trick or special case that converts that syntax from a simple assignment statement into a function definition?

Comment: f <| thing //It is also the first version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Brian already answered, the two are equivalent. Returning `fun` instead of declaring function using `let` makes difference if you want to do something (i.e. some initialization) before returning the function.

For example, if you wanted to create function that adds random number, you could write:

```
let f1 x = 
  let rnd = new System.Random()
  x + rnd.Next()

let f2 = 
  let rnd = new System.Random()
  fun y -> y + rnd.Next()
```

Here, the function `f1` creates new `Random` instance every time it is executed, but `f2` uses the same instance of `rnd` all the time (so `f2` is better way of writing this). But if you return `fun` immediately, then the F# compiler optimizes the code and the two cases are the same.

Answer (score 4):

They are equivalent (modulo the 'value restriction', which allows functions, but not values, to be generic, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131456/understanding-f-value-restriction-errors)).