# Dilemma between point free function / closure and type generic?

Tags: f#, pointfree

```
type Alignment =
     | Horizontal
     | Vertical

let getMainAttr = function
                  | Horizontal -> fst
                  | Vertical -> snd

let check alignment =
    let mainAttr = getMainAttr alignment
    mainAttr (2,3) |> ignore
    mainAttr (2.0, 3.0) // error

val getMainAttr : _arg1:Alignment -> ('a * 'a -> 'a)
mainAttr : (int * int -> int) // because of the value restriction
```

it seems the only way to make it generic is to make it explicit, e.g. `let mainAttr x = getMainAttr alignment x`

However, thus it no longer utilize closure, so that each time `mainAttr` is called `alignment` has to be checked.

Is there any way to only check `alignment` once as well as being generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Daniel describes, you're hitting the *value restriction* limitation which disallows creating generic values that are result of some F# computation (even if the value is a function). You can find more information about this in [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131456/understanding-f-value-restriction-errors) and there is also an [article about advanced points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx). The reason for this restriction is that generic values can introduce a loophole in the type safety.

In your example, you do not really need to worry, because executing the `getMainAttr` function repeatedly is not going to add that much overhead. If the function did a more complex computation, you could return an interface with a generic method (instead of a simple function):

```
/// Interface with as single generic function that selects element of a pair
type PairSelector = 
  abstract Invoke<'T> : 'T * 'T -> 'T

// Two possible implementations of the interface 
let first = { new PairSelector with member x.Invoke(a, b) = a }
let second = { new PairSelector with member x.Invoke(a, b) = b }

// Return a non-generic `PairSelector` value instead of a generic function
let getMainAttr = function
                  | Horizontal -> first
                  | Vertical -> second

// Now we can get `PairSelector` value and call it with different type arguments    
let check alignment =
    let mainAttr = getMainAttr alignment
    mainAttr.Invoke (2,3) |> ignore
    mainAttr.Invoke (2.0, 3.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is, `mainAttr` is a function *value*. Values cannot be generic. The solution, as you discovered, is to make it a "true" function by making the parameter explicit.

Regarding your last question, considering that `alignment` is a value and not a function, do you really care how many times it will be evaluated? I'm not sure, but I don't think currying will even affect this.