# Why are implicit parameters not considered compiler errors in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, currying

I am a bit new to functional programming, and while I am somewhat familiar with F#, I am still learning about all the strange ways it works.

```
//I love my Rice and Curry'd functions

let add x  = 
   let subFunction y = 
      x + y                   
   subFunction    

//explicit parameter
let add1 y = add 1 y

//implicit parameter 
let add10 = add 10

//calling it with the parameter it doesn't show that it takes
let twenty = add10 10
```

So here add10 has implicit parameters by the fact that it is calling a function that returns a function that takes a parameter. Why is it accepted that I can declare it that way instead of the same way I declared add1?

It is really deceptive as judging by its declaration it, one would assume its just an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's something coming from lambda calculus called [eta-reduction](https://www.google.com/#q=eta+reduction)

Basically it means that you can simplify your function/lambda by eliminating the last parameter on both sides of the expression when they are the same:

```
// instead of
let f x y = x + y

// in F# you can write
let f x y = (+) x y

// which is also the same as
let f x y = ((+) x) y

// then you can remove y
let f x   = (+) x

// and then remove x
let f     = (+)
```

In F# you can play with this as long as you don't reach the [value restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131456/understanding-f-value-restriction-errors). So in your code `let add1 y = add 1 y` and `let add10 = add 10` are equivalent. This is an example of how can you apply logic to reason about your code, applied to refactoring.