# Understanding type mismatch error?

Tags: f#

Why does this statement give me a type mismatch error,

```
let x = List.rev [] in (3::x, true::x);;
```

while this statement does not?

```
let x = [] in (3::x, true::x);;
```

I'm assuming it is because x is given a function call in the first statement, while it is only give an empty list in the second statement. But, I am not sure exactly why the second works and the first does not? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let x = [] ;;
```

Result: `val x : 'a list`. F# knows that `x` is a list of as-yet unknown type. If it had any contents, its type would be known. This works perfectly well.

But the following will **not** work:

```
let x = List.rev [] ;;
```

Result:

> error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'x' has been inferred to have generic type
>
> ```
> val x : '_a list
> ```
>
> Either define 'x' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

The "value restriction" error in F# can be hard to understand — why is `[]` allowed when `List.rev []` is not? — but [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/) goes into some details. Essentially, F# can always feel safe making *functions* generic, but it can only feel safe making *values* generic if the following two conditions apply:

1. The expression on the right-hand side of the `let` is a *pure* value, e.g. it has no side-effects,
   **and**
2. The expression on the right-hand side of the `let` is *immutable*.

When the expression is `[]`, then F# knows that it's a pure, immutable value, so it can make it generic (`'a list`). But when the expression is `someFunction []`, the F# compiler doesn't know what `someFunction` is going to do. Even though in this case, we know that `List.rev` is part of the standard library and matches those two scenarios, the F# compiler *can't know that*. In a completely pure language like Haskell, you can know from a function's type signature that it's pure, but F# is a more pragmatic language. So F# takes the guaranteed-safe approach and does *not* make the result of `List.rev []` generic.

Therefore, when you write `let x = [] in (3::x, true::x)`, the `[]` value is a *generic* empty list, so it can become either an `int list` or a `bool list` as needed. But when you write `let x = List.rev [] in (3::x, true::x)`, F# cannot make `List.rev []` generic. It can say "This is a list of a type I don't yet know", and wait for the type to become clear. Then the first expression of a specific type that uses this list, in this case `3::x`, will "lock" the type of that list. I.e., F# cannot consider this list to be generic, so now it has figured out that this empty list is an empty list of `int`s. And then when you try to append a `bool` to an empty `int list`, that's an error.

If you flipped the tuple around so that it was `true::x, 3::x` then the type error would "flip" as well: it would expect a `bool list` and find an `int list`.

So the short version of this answer is: **you're hitting the F# value restriction**, even though that's not immediately obvious since the error you got didn't mention value restriction at all.

See [Understanding F# Value Restriction Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1131456/2314532) for a good discussion of the value restriction, including the most common place where you'd normally see it (partially-applied functions).