# F# - Error when composing a function with itself

Tags: f#

In F# I can define an `add1` function

```
let add1 x = x + 1
```

I can then define an `add2` as the `add1` function called on itself

```
let add2 x = add1 (add1 x)
```

Or by composing the `add1` function with itself

```
let add2 = add1 >> add1
```

I was trying to implement the lambda calculus combinators in F#, the first being `Identity`

```
let I x = x
```

I then tried to define the `Identity` of `Identity`

```
let II = I >> I
```

But this caused the following compilation error:

> Value restriction. The value 'II' has been inferred to have generic
>   type
>       val II : ('_a -> '_a)     Either make the arguments to 'II' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type
>   annotation

I can however define it as

```
let II x = I (I x)
```

I'm new to F# and am curious why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with function composition itself, it's about `Value Restriction`. It happens because F# compiler infers types as generic as possible, but although it can easily generalize function, it can't generalize *value* (even though your value is in fact a function).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1132739/6198294) can help you avoid this problems, but basically you should specify an input parameter:

```
let II x = (I>>I) x
```

or

```
let II x = I >> I <| x
```

Answer (score 0):

@kagetogi is right.

The F# compiler wants to resolve values into concrete types and it will try to do so as soon as you use the function the first time. So this fails:

```
let I  x = x
let II   = I >> I
```

But this works:

```
let I  x = x
let II   = I >> I

II 5   |> printfn "%A"
```

Here `II` has type `int->int`. Which means that the following fails:

```
let I  x = x
let II   = I >> I

II 5   |> printfn "%A" 
II 5.0 |> printfn "%A"
```

Because the second call is expecting an `int` not a `float`.

That is why in F# the pipe `|>` operator is preferred over the composition operator `>>`.

```
let I   x = x
let II  x = x |>  I |> I
let II' x = x |> (I >> I)
```

Now finally `II` has generic type `'a->'a`. 
They both achieve function composition in the end.

Adding the code annotation also works:

```
let II<'a> : 'a->'a = I >> I
```