# FParsec and pipe3 make the arguments explicit or add a type notation

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I am trying to use the `pipe3` function from the `FParsec` library but I get an error I don't know how to solve.

Given the Record

```
type Point = { x: float; y: float }
```

and the following parser

```
let plistoffloats' =
    pipe3 pfloat (pchar ',' .>> spaces) pfloat 
        (fun first z second -> { x = first; y = second })
```

What I try to achieve is a parser that receives a string in format `"1.1, 3.7"` and returns a `Point`

```
run plistoffloats' "1.1, 3.7"
```

**Input** : `"1.1, 3.7"`

**Desired output** : `Point = {x = 1.1; y = 3.7;}`

**Error** :

> > error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'plistoffloats'' has been inferred to have generic type
> >         val plistoffloats' : `Parser <Point,'__a>`
> >     Either make the arguments to 'plistoffloats'' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

A simpler example with `pchar` also didn't work.

```
let parsesA = pchar 'a'
```

> > error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'parsesA' has been inferred to have generic type
> >         val parsesA : `Parser<char,'_a>`
> >     Either make the arguments to 'parsesA' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in the [FParsec documentation](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#fs-value-restriction); it will happen with any parser. The reason is because in the .Net type system, *functions* are allowed to be generic, but *values* are not — and in FParsec, you're generally defining parsers as values (e.g., you're typically writing `let psomething = ...` where `psomething` takes no parameters). Read the linked documentation page for the whole explanation — I won't copy and paste the whole thing — but the short version is that you can do one of two things:

1. Create a `test` function that looks like the following, *and make sure it's used within the same source file on your parser*:

   ```
   let test p str =
       match run p str with
       | Success(result, _, _)   -> printfn "Success: %A" result
       | Failure(errorMsg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" errorMsg
   ```
2. Annotate your parser with a type annotation like the following:

   ```
   type UserState = unit   // You might change this later
   let plistoffloats' : Parser<_, UserState> =
       // ...
   ```

It sounds like you're trying to do #1, but unless your parser is called with `test plistoffloats'` in the same source file, the F# type inference won't be able to infer your user state type and will give you that error.

P.S. You can read more about the F# value restriction error here: [Understanding F# Value Restriction Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1131456/2314532)

P.P.S. The `_` in the first position of `Parser<_, UserState>` does not mean "This type could be anything" the way `_` means in other contexts like pattern matching. Instead, `_` in a type annotation means "Please infer this type for me so that I don't have to specify it explicitly". In FParsec contexts, this is very useful because all your parsers will have `UserState` as their *second* type argument, but will have a varying type for the *first* type argument. And since the *first* type argument is the one that the type inference can infer, it means that you can copy and paste the type `Parser<_, UserState>` to all your parsers and F# will Do The Right Thing™ in each case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the link. I got the problem and why it wasn't working in the interactive when running the statements independently

Comment: If you're using the F# Interactive window, then solution 2 is the easiest. To use solution 1 in F# Interactive, you have to make sure to send *both* the parser *and* the call to `test` in the same highlighted block so that F# Interactive can have enough code to infer the user state. This can get annoying — I speak from personal experience here :-). Solution 2 means that you can highlight one parser at a time and F# Interactive will infer the types without giving you a value restriction error.