# Understanding F# value restriction

Tags: f#

I'm learning F#. I'm here because I had something hard to understand about value restriction.

Here are the examples from the book I'm studying with.

```ml
let mapFirst = List.map fst
```

Since I had learned FP with haskell, I was pretty sure that this code would be well compiled, but it was not the case. It resulted error `FS0030` (Sorry that I can't copy-paste fsi error message, since it was written in korean). Instead, I had to provide an explicit argument like:

```
let mapFirst inp = List.map fst inp   // or inp |> List.map fst
```

But why? I thought that with the above example, compiler can surely infer the type of given value:

```ml
val mapFirst : ('a * 'b) list -> 'a list
```

If I remind correctly, I called this thing in haskell *eta-conversion*, and above two examples are entirely identical. (Maybe not *entirely*, though). Why should I privide parameters explicitly to the function can be curried without any loss of information?

I've understood that something like

```ml
let empties = Array.create 100 []
```

will not compile and why, but I don't think It has something to do with my question.

※ I took a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131456/understanding-f-value-restriction-errors), but it did not help.

Comment: I don't get FS0030 on `let mapFirst = List.map fst`. What else are you doing in the function, and how do you call it? Maybe it's something to do with FSI specifically?

Comment: @Luaan I just directly typed `let mapFirst = List.map fst;;` in fsi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with mutability.

Consider this snippet:

```
type T<'a> = { mutable x : 'a option }

let t = { x = None }
```

The type of `t` is `T<'a>` - that is, `t` is generic, it has a generic parameter `'a`, meaning `t.x` can be of any type - whatever the consumer chooses.

Then, suppose in one part of the program you do:

```
t.x <- Some 42
```

Perfectly legitimate: when accessing `t` you choose `'a = int` and then `t.x : int option`, so you can push `Some 42` into it.

Then, suppose in another part of your program you do:

```
t.x <- Some "foo"
```

Oh noes, what happens now? Is `t.x : int option` or is it `string option`? If the compiler faithfully compiled your code, it would result in data corruption. So the compiler refuses, just in case.

Since in general the compiler can't really check if there is something mutable deep inside your type, it takes the safe route and rejects values (meaning "not functions") that are inferred to be generic.

---

Note that this applies to *syntactic* values, not *logical* ones. Even if your value is really a function, but isn't syntactically defined as such (i.e. lacks parameters), the value restriction still applies. As an illustration, consider this:

```
type T<'a> = { mutable x : 'a option }

let f t x = 
  t.x <- Some x

let g = f { x = None }
```

Here, even though `g` is really a function, the restriction works in exactly the same as with my first example above: every call to `g` tries to operate on the same generic value `T<'a>`

---

In some simpler cases the compiler can take a shortcut though. Thus, for example this line alone doesn't compile:

```
let f = List.map id
```

But these two lines do:

```
let f = List.map id
let x = f [1;2;3]
```

This is because the second line allows the compiler to infer that `f : list int -> list int`, so the generic parameter disappears, and everybody is happy.

In practice it turns out that this shortcut covers the vast majority of cases. The only time you *really* bump against the value restriction is when you try to export such generic value from the module.

---

In Haskell this whole situation doesn't happen, because Haskell doesn't admit mutation. Simple as that.

But then again, even though Haskell doesn't admit mutation, it kinda sorta does - via `unsafePerformIO`. And guess what - in that scenario you do risk bumping into the same problem. It's even [mentioned in the documentation](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.8/base-4.13.0.0/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO).

Except GHC doesn't refuse to compile it - after all, if you're using `unsafePerformIO`, you must know what you're doing. Right? :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm already aware of it via `empties` example in my question. I can't catch there is something to do between `mapFirst` example and your example. Isn't `mapFirst` supposed to be generic without parameter? I don't see any mutation for the value `mapFirst`...

Comment: As I already explained in the answer, the compiler is unable to prove that there is no mutation somewhere, so it takes the safe route.

Comment: I just updated the answer, added an illustration with partially applied functions.

Comment: Ah, After pondering about your elaborated answer, I managed to make a conclusion: F# compiler doesn't accept generic *value*, because later it may break type inference, so we have to explicitly give the parameter for compiler to decide the value as a function. It's why it's *value* restriction. Did I correctly understand?

Comment: Yes, more or less