# F#'s auto generalization didnt work as expected

Tags: f#, type-inference

consider the follow f# code

```
let vl x= let tem y =(x,y) in tem in let a= vl 5 in Console.WriteLine((a "4",a 3))
```

where vl has the signature 'a -> 'b -> 'a * 'b so tem is 'b -> 'a * 'b
but compiling the code produce the error message:

Error   FS0001  This expression was expected to have type
'string'
but here has type
'int'

what is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the eternally dreaded and marvelously confusing  *value restriction*.

The signature of `vl` is indeed what you expect it to be. It's the signature of `a` that can't be generic.

It can't be generic because it's syntactically a value, not a function, which is the essence of the value restriction. For a bit more info on it see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61243576/180286).

If `a` was a top-level binding, this could be fixed by explicitly giving it a generic parameter like `let a<'t> = ...`, but since it's a local binding, this doesn't work, and the only way to fix this is to give it a parameter, so it's no longer a value, but a function:

```
let vl x = let tem y = (x,y) in tem in let a z = vl 5 z in (a "4", a 3)
```